# Laravel 5: How to verify if values separated by comma from a database table field are contained in an array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

So, basically I have a field in a table from my database which contains some values separated by comma (something like: `value1, value2, value3`). I need to check somehow if one or more of these values are contained in an array of values and retrieve the model(s). I'd like a solution using Eloquent Model Query to achieve this, if not possible with Model Query, then a Query Builder solution will be okay as well, or maybe something alternative.

Comment: perhaps you should try something and post your code here. Or hire a developer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to use a function inside the `where` statement where I loop the array of values and just query the model using `like` operator to check if field value matches the values from the array and in the end I got something like this:

```
$devices = explode(",", Input::get("devices"));
$products = Product::where(function ($q) use ($devices) {
   foreach ($devices as $device) {
      $q->orWhere("compatible_devices", "like", "%" . $device . "%");
   }
})->get();
```

Works quite well so far.

Comment: I suppose this could lead to unexpected results. If you have 'value12' in your list and you filter by '%value1%' you'll get an unwanted match. You should probably review your database structure and work with a real many-to-many relation by moving those compatible_devices to their own table. This will allow you to query them correctly using a join.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I actually have a table which contains the values for compatible_devices field but I needed to make a match using only the values stored in `Product`'s compatible_devices field. I think I'll just make an additional many-to-many table for this purpose. Thank you!